# Getting data from the .next() function using axios without using console.log

Tags: javascript, axios

Below are two custom functions I've created. One of them uses the axios package. Everything works correctly except for how to ensure that the "then()" statement in the getData function adds the results to the getResults variable from the r variable.

Could someone explain to me if this is possible at all? All the examples in the reference below just `console.logs` the results.
[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

The issue being discussed in this question is not how to make the request to the rest api. But how to get the result to be added to `getGetResult`?

```
import axios from 'axios';

const getDataCount = () => {

    /**
     * Endpoint url
     */
    const DATA_COUNT_URL = '<redacted>';

    /**
     * Makes request to the endpoint.
     */
    const getData = async (url) => {
        try{
            const response = await axios.get(url);
            console.log(response.data)
            return response.data;

        }catch(err){
            console.error(err);
            process.exitCode = 1;
        }
    }   
    return getData(DATA_COUNT_URL);
};

export default getDataCount;
```

How can I get the "then()" function to add r to getResults of the getData function?

```
import getDataCount from "./data/getDataCount";

const getData = (key, initialValue) => {

    const getResult = [];
    
    // How can I get the "then()" function to add r to getResults
    getDataCount().then(r => console.log(r))

    // process result
    getResult
    
    return  'return result' ;
};

export default getData;
```